# Setting up a Grails / Groovy Server Pages project on Visual Studio Code for MacOS

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, grails, gsp

I have some HTML/CSS changes I need to make on an existing project for a client. I already cloned the repository on my machine but I'm not really sure how to set it up to view the changes locally.

I'm seeing lots of files with the .gsp extension and after some googling I discovered those files mean this is a Grails/Groovy Server Pages project, which I have zero experience with (I'm a Front End Developer btw)

I already located all the HTML/CSS code I need to change, so what I need to do is learn the basic commands to get the project running locally so I can view the changes after I make them before pushing to the actual repo.

Anybody has an idea on how to set these kinds of GSP projects up on Visual Studio Code for MacOS?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach for you would be to start Grails separately using the command prompt. Identify the version of Grails for your project, and follow the instructions from Grails to setup the dev environment.

Also, remember you probably also have some sort of database to install and initialize.